# Создаем CMS своими руками

Tags: cms, книги

Создаем свою CMS. Есть какой-либо интересный материал по изготовлению шаблонов, админки и т.д.? Вдруг кто-то видел, то что я не досмотрел.

Answer (score 1):

Например, есть туториал по созданию CMS "с нуля" от Sebastian Sulinski. Ссылок не дам, дабы не подумали что рекламирую файлообменник, - можно найти в гугле свободно и бесплатно скачать.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать погуглить так:
**IRBIS-school - курсы веб-программирования.**
*Там описаны статьи как написать свою CMS c нуля.*

Answer (score 0):

У меня была дипломная работа по созданию CMS на PHP в 2009 г. Делал по книге Д. Колисниченко "Движок для Вашего сайта" и видеоурокам Евгения Попова. Успешно защитил, но исходники не сохранились к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

На хабре была неплохая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/about_cms/51152/).